# Service Worker does not work in most of mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I've got a static site with service worker onboard that is hosted at GitLab pages and perfectly works offline on my laptop but occasionally doesn't work offline almost in any mobile browser (works in Opera Mini, but not in mobile Chrome). So I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with it.

My service worker registration script which invokes at index.html in the root of my site:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('./serviceWorker.js').then(function (registration) {
      // Registration was successful
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }, function (err) {
      // registration failed :(
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
  });
}
```

My service Worker itself:

```
let cache_v1 = 'cache_v1';

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cache_v1)
    .then(cache => cache.addAll(
      [
        './',
        './index.html',
        './favicon.png',
        './dist/bundle.js',
        './dist/style.css',
        './src/icons/soyuz_apollo192.png',
        './src/icons/soyuz_apollo_apple_icon.png',
        './src/img/asia.png',
        './src/img/pustota.jpeg',
        './src/img/zima-min.jpg'
      ]
    ))
  )
})

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(matching => {
        return matching || fetch(event.request)
      })
    )
})
```

Tell me if there is something else you need to know to help

Comment: take a look at the [Service Worker Compatability Chart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: well, I use the latest Chrome available ( which currently is 71 )
it understands service workers

Comment: Chrome Android 71?

Comment: Chrome 71 for IOS

Comment: I believe chrome only wraps webkit in iOS, so I would use the mobile safari column for compatibility, just to be sure. But even so, looks like it should have basic support...